# Create a csv file using text file with excel macro

Tags: excel, vba

Using a text file which contends in column 3 the value as hour, i would like to create a csv file using an excel macro.

The purpose is to create a csv file ( 3 lines ) which contends.

```
1 line = minimum and maximum value in column 3
2 line = write in 24 columns ( 0,1,2,3,4,5 ect )
3 line = count values for each hour, if no value is found for specific hour.. then print 0
```

**Input file**

```
123 3 04
122 3 03
122 3 03
122 3 04
122 4 04
122 5 05
122 3 12
122 4 15
122 5 21
122 5 20
122 5 20
```

**Output desired**

```
3,21
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23
0,0,0,2,3,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,2,1,0,0
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Hi PGCodeRider. Tks to answer . I am new in VBA macros.. Please help me with this case.. What is the best training course to learn VBa..

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/user/WiseOwlTutorials are the best I have seen in English

Comment: PGCodeRider. Appreciate your help and advice.

Comment: Hello! First, you need to show us your code. What have you done so far? Also please check [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Sub test()
    Dim Path As String, Fn As String
    Dim vDB, vR(), vText1(), vText2()
    Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
    Dim rngDB As Range
    Dim strResult As String
    Dim myMin As Integer, myMax As Integer
    Dim i As Long


    Set rngDB = Range("c1", Range("c" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    Set wf = WorksheetFunction

    vDB = Range("a1").CurrentRegion


    ReDim vR(1 To 3)

    myMin = wf.Min(rngDB)
    myMax = wf.Max(rngDB)
    vR(1) = myMin & "," & myMax
    ReDim vText1(23): ReDim vText2(23)
    For i = 0 To 23
        vText1(i) = i
        vText2(i) = wf.CountIf(rngDB, i)
    Next i
    vR(2) = Join(vText1, ",")
    vR(3) = Join(vText2, ",")
    strResult = Join(vR, vbCrLf)

    Path = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
    Fn = "test1.csv"
    Fn = Path & Fn
    TransToCsv strResult, Fn
End Sub
Sub TransToCsv(strTxt As String, strFile As String)
    Dim objStream As Object
    Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")

    With objStream
        '.Charset = "utf-8"
        .Open
        .WriteText strTxt
        .SaveToFile strFile, 2
        .Close
    End With
    Set objStream = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the output desired using the following macro,

```
Sub Macro1()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    '
    Set l1 = ThisWorkbook
    ruta = l1.Path & "\"
    arch = "file.txt"
    Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=ruta & arch & ".txt", _
        Origin:=xlMSDOS, StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlNone, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, _
        Tab:=True, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=True, Other:=False, _
        FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    Set l2 = ActiveWorkbook
    Set h2 = l2.Sheets(1)
    Set h3 = l2.Sheets.Add
    h3.Cells(1, "A").Value = WorksheetFunction.Min(h2.Columns("C"))
    h3.Cells(1, "B").Value = WorksheetFunction.Max(h2.Columns("C"))
    For i = 0 To 23
        h3.Cells(2, i + 1).Value = i
        h3.Cells(3, i + 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(h2.Columns("C"), i)
    Next
    l2.SaveAs Filename:=ruta & arch & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
    l2.Close False
    MsgBox "File CSV created", vbInformation
End Sub
```